# cant return value from function react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

im using function that return the length of my array 
when i print the length of array in console.log 
its appear
but when i return it in view its not show any thing!!!!
i dont know why !!! 
any help please

here is my code

```
getLengthNationalNumber ()  {

    var all_national_numbers = [];
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql("select * from service_details where service_name = ? ", [item], (tx, results) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

                let row = results.rows.item(i);
                all_national_numbers[i] = row.national_number;
                length_of_national_number = all_national_numbers.length;

                return (length_of_national_number);

            }

        });
    });

}
```

in return

```
<View>
   <Text>{this.getLengthNationalNumber}</Text>
   </View>
```

Comment: You need to call the function with brackets like this. this.getLengthNationalNumber()

Comment: @Chandini i tried , same result

Comment: your function returns a promise, that's why it's not printing the desired result. You need to maintain a state variable, and upon successful completion of db.transaction you need to update that state variable and print the same in your View

Comment: also in your for loop you're returning in the first iteration itself, not sure if you intend to do that, kindly recheck it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your function. You would need to do something like:

```
<View>
   <Text>{this.getLengthNationalNumber()}</Text>
</View>
```

or you can save the return from the function on the state, call this in `componentDidMount`, and show the value of the state. E.g:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
...
state = {
   length: 0
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.getLengthNationalNumber()
}

getLengthNationalNumber ()  {

    var all_national_numbers = [];
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql("select * from service_details where service_name = ? ", [item], (tx, results) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

                let row = results.rows.item(i);
                all_national_numbers[i] = row.national_number;
                length_of_national_number = all_national_numbers.length;

                this.setState({length: length_of_national_number})
                return (length_of_national_number);

            }

        });
    });

}
```

in return:

```
<View>
   <Text>{this.state.length}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: ,, its return the initial value of lengh  0

Comment: Did you call the function inside DidMount? Also console log something inside the function to check if the value is actually returned correctly

Comment: Okay can you `console.log("function called")` inside `getLengthNationalNumber` and see if it gets hit? And also console log the final value before the return to see if its correct, that you want

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use state variables

set the state variable in function like

```
this.setState({variableName : variableValue})
```

and user the state variable in render function like this

```
<Text>{this.state.variableName}</Text>
```

Every state variable set time, your component will going to re-render. And you can write  your function directly in componentWillMount or componentDidMount functions.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have missed the parenthesis for the method calling. If you haven't provide the parenthesis it will search for the 'variable'.

```
<Text>{this.functionName()}</Text>
```

Comment: im tired it with parenthesis ,, same result

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, **db.transaction()** looks like a async call, which will return a Promise instead of the number that you need to print.

What you can do is that you can maintain a state variable as in the below example:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
      len = 0
    }
  this.getLengthNationalNumber = this.getLengthNationalNumber.bind(this)
}

...

getLengthNationalNumber ()  {

var all_national_numbers = [];
db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql("select * from service_details where service_name = ? ", [item], (tx, results) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

            let row = results.rows.item(i);
            all_national_numbers[i] = row.national_number;
            length_of_national_number += all_national_numbers.length;

        }
       this.setState({len: length_of_national_number});

    });
  });
}

...

render(){
  return(
  <View>
     <Text>{this.state.len}</Text>
   </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: im tried , same result , it dosent change the value

Comment: can you share your full code! only thing I can see is that you might not have access to this.setState({len: length_of_national_number}); inside that function, in that case you'll need to bind the function

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have to use bind function or use arrow function like this:

```
getLengthNationalNumber = () => {
    ...
}
```

and you have return statement inside the for loop, your function is always returned in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    len = 0
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.getLengthNationalNumber()
}

getLengthNationalNumber = () =>  {

  var all_national_numbers = [];
  let length_of_national_number = 0
  db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql("select * from service_details where service_name = ? ", [item], (tx, results) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {

        let row = results.rows.item(i);
        all_national_numbers[i] = row.national_number;
        length_of_national_number += all_national_numbers.length;
      }
    });
  }).then(res => {
    this.setState({len: length_of_national_number});
  });
}

...

render(){
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>{this.state.len}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

if is not try `then` clause on `tx.executeSql`